# Modifing Arrays without using <algorithm> functions in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So first, we start with an array of 50. The range of the values within the array can be 1-100, not repeating. Then we display the highest value of that random array. Then we display the lowest value in the array. Then comes the sorting, which would be easy using the standard library functions in the `<algorithm>` header, but since it's not allowed, we need to find another way around it. Then sort from high to low.

So, to display this easily... First we start with an array[50] with random numbers between 1-100

```
72 29 11 41 31 27 21 46 43 40 17 45 30 32 25 15 19 88 22 24 51 34 99 23 26 37 1 4 2 9 33 44 12 39 38 3 47 48 5 42 49 18 54 55 87 16 28 20 50 9
```

Now we display the highest number

```
99
```

Then the lowest

```
1
```

The we sort them

```
1 2 3 4 5 9 9 11 12 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 54 55 72 87 88 99
```

Then reverse sort them

```
99 88 87 72 55 54 51 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 12 11 9 9 5 4 3 2 1
```

So.. how would I go about doing this without algorithms?

Comment: what do you mean by `without using algorithm`? generally speaking, algorithm is `a step-by-step procedure for calculations`. no hope to solve a problem while violating the definition.

Comment: I mean without using the functions from the algorithm class. Like `std::reverse(std::begin(array), std::end(array));`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: The question isn't about the STL. That's an ancient precursor to the standard C++ library (which the question specifies is not to be used anyway).

Comment: @Cryptic - `I mean without using the functions from the algorithm class`  I guess you start by writing your own functions.

Comment: You either use existing functions, or you implement your own. Don't know what is your question about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very professional but works

```
int array[50], used[50], sortedArray[50], buildSort = 1, genNum, max = 0, min = 101;
bool x;
srand(time(0));
//Array Generator
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

        do{
        genNum = (1+rand()%100);

        x = false;
        for(int j =0; j < 50; j++){
                if(genNum == used[j]){
                           x = true;
                           }
                }
                }while(x == true);
        used[i] = genNum;
        array[i] = genNum;
        }
        cout << "Numbers: ";
for(int d = 0; d < 50; d++){
        cout << array[d] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;

//Max and Min finder
for(int m = 0; m < 50; m++){
        if(array[m] > max){
                    max = array[m];
                    }
        if(array[m] < min){
                    min = array[m];
                    }
        }
cout << "Max is: " << max << endl;
cout << "Min is: " << min << endl << endl;

//Sorting
sortedArray[0] = min;
for(int v = min+1; v <= max; v++){

        for(int r = 0; r < 50; r++){
                if(array[r] == v){
                               sortedArray[buildSort] = array[r];
                               buildSort++;
                            }
                }

        }
cout << "Sorted: ";
for(int k = 0; k < 50; k++){
        cout << sortedArray[k] << " ";
        }
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "Reverse sorting: ";
for(int l = 49; l >=0; l--){
        cout << sortedArray[l] << " ";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitset sort since the range of values of the array is limited to 1-100, and there is no repetition you can have a bitset array of 100 ints where each index specifies can be a 0 (that number isn't in the array) or a 1 (the number is in the array).  For example the array [1, 5, 3] can be represented by the bitset array [1, 0, 1, 0, 1].

pseudo code:

```
MAX_SIZE = 100
bitset = new int[MAX_SIZE]
smallest = biggest = -1
for each value in array {
  smallest = value if value < smallest
  biggest = value if value > biggest
  bitset[value-1] = 1
}

sorted = (i for i in 0..bitset.length - 1 if bitset[i] == 1)    
reverse_sorted = (sorted[i] for i in sorted.length-1..0)
```

Comment: That's a "counting sort"

Comment: +1 It's well to add information, if one element can appear more than once it's possible to use bucket sort.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is by using loops.

For example, to traverse an array, printing every element, we could use a loop like:

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

All of the problems you mention, except sorting, can be done using a simple loop like the one above.  You'll have to do your own bookkeeping in order to solve the problems, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

As for sorting, that's a more challenging problem.  You might start with the wikipedia article to see how that is handled.  You probably want to try implementing [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sor).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have not checked this code and I'm sure it has some errors in it, but hopefully this will at least give you some ideas and a good base to go off of:

```
/******************
*
* Your array should have 51 spots.
* The last element should be 0.
*
******************/

uint8_t findMax(uint8_t *arrayToSearch){
    // Your array should end in a sentinel value of 0
    uint8_t highest = 0;
    for(; *arrayToSearch; arrayToSearch++){
        highest = (*arrayToSearch > highest) ? *arrayToSearch : highest;
    }
    return highest;
}

uint8_t findMin(uint8_t *arrayToSearch){
    // Your array should end in a sentinel value of 0
    uint8_t lowest = 101;
    for(; *arrayToSearch; arrayToSearch++){
        lowest = (*arrayToSearch < lowest) ? *arrayToSearch : lowest;
    }
    return lowest;
}

void sortAscending(uint8_t *arrayToSearch){
    // sort from low to high
    // get count of array (According to your question, it should be 50, but we'll verify)
    unsigned short count = 0;
    uint8_t *countingPoint;
    countingPoint = arrayToSeach; // make countingPoint point to the first element
    while(*countingPoint){ 
        count++;
        countingPoint++;
    }

    // now we'll create a second array
    uint8_t sortedArray[count];
    // now let's begin sorting.
    unsigned long int totalIterations = 0;
    while(totalIterations < count){
        uint8_t currentSmallest = 101; // value which will not ever exist.
        signed long int smallestIndex = -1;
        unsigned short offset = 0;
        uint8_t *startOfArray;
        startOfArray = arrayToSearch;
        for(; *startOfArray; *startOfArray++, offset++){
            if(currentSmallest > *startOfArray){
                smallestIndex = offset;
                currentSmallest = *startOfArray;
            }
        } /* end for */
        sortedArray[totalIterations] = currentSmallest;
        *(smallestIndex + arrayToSearch) = 101; /* set the value above 100 so it will be
                                                   skipped in the next for loop */
        totalIterations++;
    } /* end while */

    /* now we'll the sorted values to the array to search */
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < count; i++){
        *(i+arrayToSearch) = sortedArray[i];
    }
    // and we're done.
}

/*
 * We can actually write sortDescending the same way and just modify
 * the last loop to put them in reverse order
 */
void sortDescending(uint8_t *arrayToSearch){
    // sort from low to high and then order as high to low
    // get count of array (According to your question, it should be 50, but we'll verify)
    unsigned short count = 0;
    uint8_t *countingPoint;
    countingPoint = arrayToSeach; // make countingPoint point to the first element
    while(*countingPoint){ 
        count++;
        countingPoint++;
    }

    // now we'll create a second array
    uint8_t sortedArray[count];
    // now let's begin sorting.
    unsigned long int totalIterations = 0;
    while(totalIterations < count){
        uint8_t currentSmallest = 101; // value which will not ever exist.
        signed long int smallestIndex = -1;
        unsigned short offset = 0;
        uint8_t *startOfArray;
        startOfArray = arrayToSearch;
        for(; *startOfArray; *startOfArray++, offset++){
            if(currentSmallest > *startOfArray){
                smallestIndex = offset;
                currentSmallest = *startOfArray;
            }
        } /* end for */
        sortedArray[totalIterations] = currentSmallest;
        *(smallestIndex + arrayToSearch) = 101; /* set the value above 100 so it will be
                                                   skipped in the next for loop */
        totalIterations++;
    } /* end while */

    /* now we'll copy the values to the arrayToSearch in reverse order */
    int i;
    for(i=(count-1); i >= 0; i--){
        *(i+arrayToSearch) = sortedArray[i];
    }
    // and we're done.
}

/* calling these */
int main(){
    uint8_t yourArray[51];
    // ... your code to populate this array
    yourArray[50] = 0; // set the last spot to 0.

    uint8_t highest = findMax(yourArray);
    uint8_t lowest = findMin(yourArray);

    // now make yourArray sorted by lowest to highest
    sortAscending(yourArray);
    // ... Whatever you need to do with it in ascending order.

    // now make it sorted by highest to lowest
    sortDescending(yourArray);
    // ... Whatever you need to do with it in descending order.

    return 0;
}
```

I'm a C-programmer so this is a rather C-style answer.

Some additional information that might be helpful can be found at:

- http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-sort-array-ascending-order/
- http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

The Wikipedia page (last link) might seem a little overwhelming, but there is a lot of great content on it.

I hope this will be of some help to you. Again, I'm not sure if the code I included will work properly. It's merely meant to convey the general idea.